# Error happens when API returns JSON, Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use API the console shows this `warning`

```
Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

The error happens here

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/api/moods/`)
    .then((res)=> {
    setResult(res.data.items);
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
  }, []);
```

However my API returns `json` which has unique `key`

Why does it happen?

It doesn't a big matter for program working.
I would appreciate if any help.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "happy time",
            "key": "happy",
            "order": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "sad time",
            "key": "sad",
            "order": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "normal time",
            "key": "normal",
            "order": 2
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "api": "Mood"
    }
}
```

Comment: [React - keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). React needs a `key` prop on a react element to update the DOM efficiently. This warning has nothing to do with the `key` property in objects.

Comment: Where are you using `result`? Can you show where the error originates?

Comment: The error should arise from the pace you are rendering the result in your component. Could you add the code for that

Comment: The issue is with where you **use** whatever state variable `setResult` sets (`result`, usually, although in general you use plurals for arrays and lists). Please show that code. But fundamentally: Your *component*, not your data object, needs to have a unique key. (You can probably use `key={item.key}` when rendering those items).

Comment: I use `result` here as loop `{result.map(item => (
          <FormControlLabel value={item.key} control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label={item.name}/>
        ))}` and I add 'key={item.key}' it fixed. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could be iterating over the state without signing the "key" property. Note the "key" property on the below code (it should be unique):

```
return (
  <ul>
    {
      result.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
)
```